# Javascript - If statement with conditions dependent on 2 separate form id

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to hide a div, depending on the answers of 2 questions above. Both need to be "N" to hide. But struggling to figure out how to get both IDs as variables within the script.

Hope you can help...

```
<div><table><tr>
<td><input name="v2_1a" type="radio" id="v2_1a" value="Y"></td>
<td><input name="v2_1a" type="radio" id="v2_1a" value="N"></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><input name="v2_1b" type="radio" id="v2_1b" value="Y"></td>
<td><input name="v2_1b" type="radio" id="v2_1b" value="N"></td>
</tr></table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("input[name$='v2_1b']").click(function() {
$(".expand1").show();
var value1 = document.getElementById('v2_1a');
var value2 = $(this).val();
if (value1 == 'Y') {
$(".expand1").show();
}
else (value1 == 'N' && value2 == 'N') {
$(".expand1").hide();
}
});
</script> 
<div id="expand1" class="expand1" style="display:inline-block;">
</div>
```

Comment: On a side note, make sure not to confuse `else` with `elseif`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the checked value of a radio group by adding the `:checked` selector to your query:

```
var value1 = $("input[name='v2_1a']:checked").val();
var value2 = $("input[name='v2_1b']:checked").val();
```

Read more about the selector at http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/.

---

To detect a change in either radio group, you can use the following code:

```
$("input[name='v2_1a'],input[name='v2_1b']").change(function() {
  // Do your checks here
});
```

Edit: added an example on how to detect changes in either radio group.

Comment: Thank you, that worked, I just need to adjust it so it checks this on updates of either.

Comment: @user2401569: I've added an example on how to do that. Use this instead of the `click()` function you currently call.

Comment: thank you very much for your prompt reply and working solution.

Answer (score 1):

`Ids` must be unique.No two elements have same id.You can a pply the same class to them

change

```
  else (value1 == 'N' && value2 == 'N') {
```

to

```
else if(value1 == 'N' && value2 == 'N') {


var temp1 =     $('input:radio[name='v2_1a']:checked').val();
var temp2 =    $('input:radio[name='v2_1b']:checked').val();


if (temp1 == 'Y') 
   $(".expand1").show();

if(temp1  =='N' && temp2 == 'N')
 //hide
```

Comment: Also, its better practice to always use `===` except when you know what you are doing...

Comment: And how does this answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the same ID twice within the document, so change that, and target the elements by name, checking if both 'N' values are checked, and toggling the elements visibility based on that :

```
var elems = $('input[name^="v2_1"]');

elems.on('change', function () {
    var n = elems.filter(':checked').length > 1 ? $.map(elems, function(e,i) {return e.checked?e.value:'N'}) : ['Y']
    $(".expand1").toggle(n.indexOf('Y') != -1);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/SDBza/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is little unclear,

```
 <div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Group 1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Yes<input name="v2_1a" type="radio" class="radio" id="v2_1a_y" value="Y" /></td>
        <td>No<input name="v2_1a" type="radio" class="radio" id="v2_1a_n" value="N" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> Group 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Yes<input name="v2_1b" type="radio" class="radio" id="v2_1b_y" value="Y" /></td>
        <td>No<input name="v2_1b" type="radio" class="radio" id="v2_1b_n" value="N" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is a js fiddle to get name, value and ID on click of radio button.
http://jsfiddle.net/uvYgL/1/

JS

```
jQuery('body').on('click','.radio', function(){
  var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
  var name = jQuery(this).attr('name');
  var input_val = jQuery('#'+id).val();

})
```

Please add some details what else you need?